# How do I set the default value to "default" in a Tesspec in Jira. When I use Call to Test

Tags: jira

In Jira, there is a possibility to create Testspecs. In those Testspecs I am able to call another Test with a set of values/variables. In my (Sub)Test I define the default values for those variabels. But when I call to this test by default it is always set to manuall input and i have to select default value for each variable. Is there a a way to awoid this Sisyphus work?

[image]